# Start loop from the 15th of the month

Tags: wordpress, date, loops

I'm trying to create a loop that shows me all the posts starting the 15th of the month.

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');

query_posts( "cat=22&year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&order=ASC" );
```

This doesn't work because it starts the posts from the 1st of the current month. Thank you!

P.S. Not the posts FROM the 15th, but starting with the 15th of the month.

Answer (score 0):

The standard query interfaces don't support this. You'll need to fetch the posts for the month and filter them in your processing loop.

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');
query_posts( "cat=22&year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&order=ASC" );
...
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        if ( intval(get_the_date('j')) >= 15 ) {
            // display the post
        }
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```